# Тогглер анимации элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Я уже час пытаюсь починить тогглер анимации элемента. Его суть просто вопспроизвести CSS анимацию в обе стороны: для открытия и закрытия блока, с последующим его срытием (`displa: none` или `visibility: hidden` без разницы).

Анимация выглядит следующим образом:

```js
$('.modal').toggleClass("modal-active");
```

```css
.modal {
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.modal>div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.modal>div>div {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.modal>div>div, .modal {
    transition: opacity, margin-bottom 0.4s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.modal-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.modal-active>div>div {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Тут по сути просто прозрачность с 0 до 1 и небольшой сдвиг блока сверху margin'ом.

Я видел варианты проиграть анимацию реверсивно, но я не пойму пока сделает ли это работу с ней удобнее, пока нет. В основном проблема в том что в одну из сторон блок пропадает сразу, так есть `visibility: hidden` срабатывает раньше. Я мог бы это исправить неудобными методами типа `setTimeout` но хотелось бы больше гибкости и меньше кода, если это реально.

Есть какой-либо вариант реализовать это без трекинга окончания анимации(или чего подобного) с просто `toggleClass`, то есть на CSS?

Comment: > Есть какой-либо вариант реализовать это без трекинга окончания анимации

А как вы без этого узнаете, когда закончилась анимация?

Comment: @ThisMan я хочу верить что в CSS есть какой-то вариант переместить `visibility: hidden` в конец анимации, или есть какие-либо претранзишн правила, которые выполняются до начала анимации или что анимацию можно прокрутить в обще стороны, что даст `visibility` всегда в конце или что-либо еще. Ставить таймаут значит для изменения тайминов нужно заменить и значение в js, а я 100% забуду это сделать и буду искать проблемы...

Comment: Вам нужный `keyframes`, возможно они работают с `visibility`

Comment: добавь html!!!!

Comment: И кстати,  displa: none анимация не будет работать, для этого есть opacity